# How do I reconcile my Google Analytics numbers with my Squarespace analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

According to Squarespace, in the last month I got Page Views 259, Unique Visitors 172, and Robot Hits 1,965. According to Google Analytics it was more like 346 page views, and 97 Uniques (no data on robots).

I currently have filters for self traffic (exclude home/work) on both analytics. How do I go about reconciling the two, or believing either one?[Here is a link to the exported analytics; sorry pdf](https://docs.google.com/viewer?a=v&pid=explorer&chrome=true&srcid=0BwWH_7dsgkAqNjk5YTVjMjEtNDJiOS00OTU2LWFlOGEtZmViYjkzZmMxOGYy&hl=en&authkey=CIGWvuQF)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is bound to be some small differences between numbers on two different analytics packages. I would start by looking to see:

- Am I tracking every page on both packages?
- Are the tracking scripts in different places? (ie top of page and bottom)

I don't know how Squarespace runs their analytics. However, do a little bit of research on it. If they use Javascript tracking the same way Google does, then those questions apply. If they are reading from your server log files (like Webalizer does) then they would be the more accurate tracker.

Comment: Oh geez, thanks for re-wiring what I wasn't thinking of off the top. Squarespace pointed me at Actionable-Analytics once I started looking into how their proprietary is administered and that's some messy stuff.